# SC Clearance in UK in order to work

Tags: united-kingdom, working-visas

I have an EEA Family permit (EEA FP) until June 2017. I arrived in UK almost 3 weeks ago and I am searching for a job as Software Engineer. Five recruitment agencies called me but all asked me to be SC Cleared.

I want to ask if it is possible for me (Non European, married with an European and that lived 3 years and a half in Italy and worked in Italy) to obtain the SC Clearance, because I saw in internet that I cannot ask it for by myself, but a sponsor (an enterprise that is interested to hire me) has to ask it for me.

Do you know what can I do? Because all the recruitment agencies say that I need to be SC Cleared, but, how can I be SC cleared if I have lived in England only for 3 weeks and I don't have a enterprise that ask the SC Clearance for me?

Do you know if there is another document that can replace the SC clearance?

Do you know how can I convince an enterprise to ask for me the SC clearance?

Please help me. I don't know what to do!

Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Specific to your question, [this site gives a good overview the types](https://www.cwjobs.co.uk/careers-advice/security-clearance/Types%20of%20national%20security%20clearance) and process. Note that _To gain (SC) clearance you will normally need to have been a UK resident for a minimum of 5 years, and will need to successfully complete all stages of the vetting process...._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to find a company who is willing to go for you through the hassle of getting you cleared. That usually means that you must be an extraordinary candidate, as simply put, there are a lot of great candidates out there who already underwent SC.

Your best solution, if you cannot find a company who wishes to sponsor you, is to seek a job as a developer in a field that doesn't require SC. And that would be a vast majority of them, as very few companies work with secret+ assets.